# Finding the limit of a sequence 4

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to find the limit of the sequence,

$$f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{n}$$

for $x\in [0,1]$

I am just wondering if it is $f(x)=0$ because when $x=1$ then $\frac{x^n}{n}=\frac{1}{n}=0$ and when it is $x\leq 1$ the numerator goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Or is there a more mathematical approach to this result?

Comment: Prove that $\forall x \in [0,1]: \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$

Comment: @DHMO how do I go about that?

Comment: How deep do you need? Do you need to do it epsilon-delta style?

Comment: I was showing that the sequence converges uniformly but first I wanted to find its limit, showing that the sequence converges uniformly is easy but shouldn't I find its limit first?

Comment: The limit is $0$. One way to see it: for each $x$, this sequence is a multiplication of a bounded sequence ($x^n$) and a sequence whose limit is $0$ ($1/n$)

Comment: Why do you need to show that the sequence converges uniformly?

Comment: this is just a part of the question I just wanted clarification why the limit was $f(x)=0$, I just wanted help with the limit part

Comment: @35T41 that makes sense, but I cant take the $x^n$ outside of the limit right? since it involves a n?

Comment: @fr14 He is saying that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{x^n}n = \lim_{n \to \infty} x^n \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1n$

Comment: okay so its a bounded sequence multipled by 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in fact the function $x \mapsto 0$ on $[0,1]$ is the uniform limit of the sequence $(f_{n})$. To see this, note that $x \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ imply
$$
\frac{x^{n}}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Note that $1/n \to 0$; so $f_{n} \to 0$ on $[0,1]$ uniformly.

If you want an epsilon-analysis: 
If $\varepsilon > 0$, then there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ (say $N := \lfloor \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \rfloor + 1$) ensuring $n \geq N$ implies $1/n < \varepsilon$. So $n \geq N$ implies $|\frac{x^{n}}{n}-0| = \frac{x^{n}}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$ for all $x \in [0,1]$; this shows that $(f_{n})$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ to the function $x \mapsto 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t\in [0,1]$.

Note that $0 \leq t^n \leq 1$, and therefore $0 \leq t^n/n \leq 1/n$. Take the limit and use the sandwich's theorem.